# Identity for compositum and intersection of fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, field-extensions

Let $k$ be an arbitrary base field and $K, L, M$ some fields over $k$ contained  in a fixed overfield $\Omega$.

**Question:** Are there some "reasonable" assumptions (ie beyond a bunch of really "boring" assumptions) on $K, L, M$ which imply that

$$  K(M\cap L)=MK\cap LK $$

holds? Maybe something with linear disjointness? Concrete conjecture( see for motivation below why this guess): If $L$ and $K$ linearly disjoint to $M$? If yes, how to see in that case the inclusion   $K(M\cap L)\supset MK\cap LK$?

Original motivation leading me to this problem: Even thought this looks elementary I still haven't found a satisfying argument why following equality holds: assume $k \subset K \subset L$ an arbitrary tower of not neccessary finite *algebraic extensions* of $k$ and $M=k(t)$ the field of Laurent series. Then I expect that it should hold

$$ (k(t) \cdot K) \cap L = K $$

independently how the involved fields are embedded in overfield $\Omega$, but I still not see how to deduce the inclusion $ (k(t) \cdot K) \cap L \subset K $, even thought that it looks "plausible". Does somebody see a quick trick how to seee it?

Since in this special situation $L=LK$ and $M$ linearly disjoint to $L$, we clearly have $L \cap M =k$, this can be translated to the problem above.

I noticed that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674591/relationship-between-intersection-and-compositum-of-fields) was posted identical question, with primary focus on number fields, but unfortunarely not received any answer.

#UPDATE: As @Wojowu pointed out posing certain assumtions on linear disjointness relations between the involved fields not give the statement. What about if we pose the "very" restrictive assumtion that $K \subset L$ algebraic over $k$ and $M$ purely transcendental over $k$, like in "*original motivation*" part? (Not sure where it can be really weakened)

Comment: The conjecture fails even for algebraic extensions with linear disjointness assumption - take $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}),L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}),M=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{6})$. Then $MK=LK=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, but $K(M\cap L)=K$.

Comment: @Wojowu: right, so looks not so promising in case all $K,L,M$ were algebraic ext'ns. If one were to lower expectations even further orientating on the "original motivation"-paragraph, is it at least true if say $K \subset L$ algebraic over $k$, and $M$ purely transcendental?

Comment: Regarding "Original motivation": $k((t))\cdot K\subseteq K((t))$, and $K((t))/K$ is regular, hence linearly disjoint from $L/K$